# How do i get the html selection out of a javascript range object?

Tags: javascript, range, getselection

i have a document that i am trying to pull the highlighted text and accompanying html content. Everything is working fine using window.getSelection(), however when i need to extract the specific html content things start to get sticky.

I am trying to determine if the highlighted text has crossed halfway through any other html tags, but all methods i can find to extract the html contents seem to be also adding html tags to the document that werent there before. this is a problem, as i need to know the users selection against the native document. does anyone know a workaround to this issue?

i have tried using

```
var sel = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)
sel.cloneContents()
```

and then proceeding from there, but that always returns additional html tags when i test it halfway through an italicized node.

i have also tried using the rangy library

```
var sel = rangy.getSelection()
console.log(sel.toHtml())
```

but that returned the same problems. it seems that any method that returns a documentFragment object seems to make assumptions about the selected text, and i need to avoid that.

anybody have any ideas? im stumped. thanks!

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what you're trying to do? The crucial bit is *"I am trying to determine if the highlighted text has crossed halfway through any other html tags"* and it's unclear to me exactly what you mean by that.